# jquery change not working after implementing autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, select, autocomplete, onchange

I have a `select-option` `html dropdown` list in which some event occurs when we change the values from the list. No I needed to add autocomplete in the same list. But after implementing autocomplete , though autocomplete is working the `change` event is not working ! Whats the matter ?

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc49r/1/)

Comment: please provide relevant code in question. And see rendered HTML, the generated INPUT is no more the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the rendered html code is in inside iframe so you cannot apply jquery events and second thing is that the autocomplete has completely changed the DOM properties of the selectbox .